# CI for Qt app: build with different Qt versions

Tags: c++, qt, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I use Travis-CI for continuous integration for my simple Qt app. My .travis.yml file looks like this (based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jreese/6207161)):

```
language: cpp

before_install:
  - sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install -qq g++ qt4-qmake libqt4-dev qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev

script: 
  - qmake -qt=qt4 -v
  - qmake -qt=qt4
  - make
  - make -k check
  - make clean
  - qmake -qt=qt5 -v
  - qmake -qt=qt5
  - make
  - make -k check
```

This configuration allows me to build my app (and run tests) with default Qt libraries in Ubuntu (Qt 4.8.1 and Qt 5.0.2).

Is there any way to build app with other Qt versions (4.7.x, 4.8.x, 5.1.x and so on)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inspired by [AlexandreP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29722508/1536843) answer and [.travis.yml file of Twofold-Qt project](https://github.com/hicknhack-software/Twofold-Qt/blob/develop/.travis.yml) with many thanks to [Stephan Binner](https://launchpad.net/~beineri).

```
language: cpp

matrix:
 include:
  - os: linux
    dist: trusty
    sudo: required
    compiler: gcc
    env:
     - QT_BASE=48
  - os: linux
    dist: trusty
    sudo: required
    compiler: gcc
    env:
     - QT_BASE=51
  - os: linux
    dist: trusty
    sudo: required
    compiler: gcc
    env:
     - QT_BASE=52
  - os: linux
    dist: trusty
    sudo: required
    compiler: gcc
    env:
     - QT_BASE=53
  - os: linux
    dist: trusty
    sudo: required
    compiler: gcc
    env:
     - QT_BASE=54
  - os: linux
    dist: trusty
    sudo: required
    compiler: gcc
    env:
     - QT_BASE=55
  - os: osx
    compiler: clang
    env:
     - QT_BASE=55
  - os: linux
    dist: trusty
    sudo: required
    compiler: gcc
    env:
     - QT_BASE=56
  - os: linux
    dist: trusty
    sudo: required
    compiler: gcc
    env:
     - QT_BASE=57
  - os: osx
    compiler: clang
    env:
     - QT_BASE=57

before_install:
  - if [ "$QT_BASE" = "48" ]; then sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt487-trusty -y; fi
  - if [ "$QT_BASE" = "51" ]; then sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt511-trusty -y; fi
  - if [ "$QT_BASE" = "52" ]; then sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt521-trusty -y; fi
  - if [ "$QT_BASE" = "53" ]; then sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt532-trusty -y; fi
  - if [ "$QT_BASE" = "54" ]; then sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt542-trusty -y; fi
  - if [[ "$QT_BASE" = "55" && "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" = "linux" ]]; then sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt551-trusty -y; fi
  - if [ "$QT_BASE" = "56" ]; then sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt562-trusty -y; fi
  - if [[ "$QT_BASE" = "57" && "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" = "linux" ]]; then sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt571-trusty -y; fi
  - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" = "linux" ]; then 
      sudo apt-get update -qq;
    else
      brew update;
    fi

install:
  - if [ "$QT_BASE" = "48" ]; then sudo apt-get install -qq opt-qt4-qmake opt-qt4-dev-tools; source /opt/qt-4.8/bin/qt-4.8-env.sh; fi
  - if [ "$QT_BASE" = "51" ]; then sudo apt-get install -qq qt51base; source /opt/qt51/bin/qt51-env.sh; fi
  - if [ "$QT_BASE" = "52" ]; then sudo apt-get install -qq qt52base; source /opt/qt52/bin/qt52-env.sh; fi
  - if [ "$QT_BASE" = "53" ]; then sudo apt-get install -qq qt53base; source /opt/qt53/bin/qt53-env.sh; fi
  - if [ "$QT_BASE" = "54" ]; then sudo apt-get install -qq qt54base; source /opt/qt54/bin/qt54-env.sh; fi
  - if [ "$QT_BASE" = "55" ]; then
      if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" = "linux" ]; then 
        sudo apt-get install -qq qt55base; source /opt/qt55/bin/qt55-env.sh; 
      else
        brew install qt55;
        brew link --force qt55;
      fi
    fi
  - if [ "$QT_BASE" = "56" ]; then sudo apt-get install -qq qt56base; source /opt/qt56/bin/qt56-env.sh; fi
  - if [ "$QT_BASE" = "57" ]; then
      if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" = "linux" ]; then 
        sudo apt-get install -qq qt57base; source /opt/qt57/bin/qt57-env.sh; 
      else
        brew install qt5;
        brew link --force qt5;
      fi
    fi

script:
  - qmake -v
  - qmake -r
  - make

notifications:
  email: false
```

With this .travis.yml you will get 10 separate build jobs - number of elements in matrix section. Each build job will install specified Qt version and use it for app building in Ubuntu with Qt 4.8 - 5.7 and OS X with Qt 5.5 and 5.7 (or latest version).

If you want to build your app for Windows, you can try [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/) CI service. Example config (Qt 5.3 - 5.7):

```
version: '{build}'

init:
- git config --global core.autocrlf input

environment:
  matrix:
  - QT5: C:\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32
    MINGW: C:\Qt\Tools\mingw482_32
  - QT5: C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32
    MINGW: C:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32
  - QT5: C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32
    MINGW: C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32
  - QT5: C:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32
    MINGW: C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32
  - QT5: C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32
    MINGW: C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32

matrix:
  fast_finish: true

before_build:
- set PATH=%MINGW%\bin;%QT5%\bin;%PATH%

build_script:
- qmake -v
- qmake -r
- mingw32-make
```

I use these configs in my project - [qtcsv](https://github.com/iamantony/qtcsv). See it for updates and build logs.

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/$BEINEREPO -y`

Answer (score 4):

You can find more version of Qt by adding this beineri's ppa.
For example, version 5.4 can be added:

```
before_install:
  - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt541 -y
install:
  - sudo apt-get install qt54base qt54websockets
script:
  - source /opt/qt54/bin/qt54-env.sh
```

Comment: Beineri supports Qt 5.5 as well; just substitute `qt55` where required!

Comment: And what about OS X?